# endpoints-proto-datastore: return different class then the input class

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

I want to have an endpoint which gets a certain type of object and returns a different type of object , instead of having them the same type.

for example:

```
class SomeClass(EndpointsModel):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()

class OtherClass(EndpointsModel):
    otherName = ndb.StringProperty()

@SomeClass.method(path='mymodel', http_method='POST', name='mymodel.insert')
def MyModelInsert(self, my_model):
    my_model.put()
    otherModel = OtherClass(otherName='someothername')
    return otherModel
```

currently i'm getting:

```
ServerError (Method MyApi.MyModelInsert expected response type <class '.SomeClass'>, sent <class '.OtherClass'>)
```

Is there any way to have the input Class different from the return Class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can supply a `response_message` parameter in the method decorator, but that parameter has to be a ProtoRPC message class and not an EndpointsModel.

You can get the message class from the EndpointsModel via the `ProtoModel` classmethod.

And you have to return a ProtoRPC message and not an EndpointsModel from your method since the library doesn't do the conversation automatically for custom response classes. You can do this using the `ToMessage` method of the model.

To summarize you would have this code (untested):

```
@SomeClass.method(path='mymodel',
                  http_method='POST',
                  name='mymodel.insert'
                  response_message=OtherClass.ProtoModel())
def MyModelInsert(self, my_model):
    my_model.put()
    otherModel = OtherClass(otherName='someothername')
    return otherModel.ToMessage()
```